# Does Azure AzCopy across containers within the same storage account behave like across storage accounts?

Tags: azure, azure-storage

I would like to understand a bit more about the viability of my use case. Say I have 2 tiers of data, tier1 and tier2. Each tier would have bunch of files. I would like to promote data from tier2 into tier1 if I believe they have passed some checks. Now with Azure Blob I can see there are 3 possible set ups:

1. Same storage account with 2 containers tier1 and tier2. Use azcopy to move data from tier2 into tier1
2. Different storage account (tier1 and tier2). Use azcopy to move data from tier2 into tier1
3. Same storage account + same container: use tier1/tier2 as the "path prefix" and just rename when I want to promote.

3 seems cumbersome. I would like to understand if 1 or 2 is better. Better is defined by 1) faster 2) less Azure cost

I tried looking up https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/common/storage-use-azcopy-v10 but I do not see documentation covering my use case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would be charged for a copy for either between containers or accounts, so options 1 and 2 would be the same as far as I can see.

Could I suggest you look at [metadata](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/blobs/storage-blob-properties-metadata) or [index tags](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/blobs/storage-manage-find-blobs?tabs=azure-portal) to label your blobs?

Metadata is included in the storage costs for a blob. While Blobs are charged a fixed cost per index tag (see [pricing page](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-gb/pricing/details/storage/blobs/)).

You can filter on both as they are not a move operation, in theory, would be quicker though you may want to test.